# Convert Unique String to an unique integer value in C++

Tags: c++, string, int, integer, ascii

In my project there is a requirement to identify strings uniquely. I wonder if there is any easy way to represent a unique string with an unique integer value. Maybe it is related with ASCII value of characters but I could not figure out how to do it.
Eg: I want string "ankit" to represent with an unique value. This unique integer value should only represent string "ankit". And also I want to convert this unique int to correct string associated with it. I hope you understand. If not you can ask.

The maximum string length is 32.

As an example:

Suppose we have 4 Strings. `"ankit"` with value `5`. next input is `"John"` with value `6`. Next input is `"ankit"` with value `3` and than `"ankit"` with value `3`. So what I want store cumulative sum of corresponding strings in a single array at their respective position of occurences.

Here one array will be created of size n(no. of strings).  `arr[n]` it  will store `arr[0]=5` , `arr[1]=6` ,`arr[2]=8` , `arr[3]=11`.

Comment: are you looking for a [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) (with the additional constraint that the values are unique) ?

Comment: is there is no way to do with simple way without using STL. I mean by making use of ASCII values or anything

Comment: using the standard library **is** the simple way, but anyhow I am still trying to understand what you actually want to do. Please add an example and any code you have written so far would help

Comment: Strings can be any size. So to represent any string as an integer, you also need integers that can be any size. C++ doesn't have this built in, you need a third party library, for instance MPIR or GMP. But I think probably you don't really need this. Please explain what you are trying to do really, and maybe someone can suggest a better way than what you are trying at the moment.

Comment: @john I just want to create hash for string.

Comment: @AnkitMishra But hashes aren't unique and they can't be reversed. You can't go from the hash back to the string. Please explain *carefully* what you are really trying to do, At the moment we are just guessing.

Comment: what do you need that hash for? If all you need is a set of unique strings, and the hash is your solution to that, then use a `std::set`

Comment: @AnkitMishra At the moment, if we take what you say literally, then you need a multiple precision integer library, like MPIR or GMP, as I suggested.

Comment: see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and please try to explain  the acutal problem you want to solve, not only your attempt to solve that problem (the one we don't really know what it is)

Comment: There are around 96 printable characters. With 7 characters you can generate more combinations than 4-byte int can hold. With 11 characters you can generate more combinations than 8-byte int can hold. As long as your strings are shorter, you can use a conversion to int. If your strings are longer, it won't work.

Comment: @john Suppose we have 3 Strings. "ankit" with value 5. next input is "John" with value 6. Next input is "ankit" with value 3. SO what I want to do is make two array because we have two unique string and we will store cumulative sum.  Here two array will be created of sizes equals to no. of occurrence of the strings. Here arr1[2] because string "ankit" occured twice and arr2[1] because "john" occured once.  Data in Array 1 will be arr1[0]=5, arr1[1]=8. Data in Array 2 will be arr2[0]=6.

Comment: You don't need hashes for that:  `std::unorderd_map<std::string, int>` is what you could use.

Comment: `map["ankit"] += 5; map["John"] += 6; map["ankit"] += 3`

Comment: @ThomasSablik Got it.

Comment: @ThomasSablik max string length could be 32. I know for sure

Comment: I edited your comment in the question, because it should be there

Comment: You can generate about `2708192040014184559945134363758220403329915059847434832829218816` different strings with 32 printable characters. That won't fit into an int.

Comment: yes true. I will use map

Comment: that cumulative sum is something new. Please make sure to be clear in the question what you want. Only after editiing your question and reading it again I noticed that cumulative sum thingy. Details in comments are easily overlooked

Comment: @idclev463035818 I did check it out

Comment: @AnkitMishra you made it less clear. Where do `arr[2]=8 , arr[3]=11` come from?

Comment: @idclev463035818 i edited again. index 2 is cummulative sum of ankit at 1st and 3rd occurence.

Comment: @AnkitMishra `std::map<string, int>` or `std::unordered_map<string, int>` are what you need.

Answer (score 2):

To map `std::string`s to integers you can use a `std::unordered_map<std::string,int>`. If you want to map `std::string`s to some cumulative sum of integers, that would be a `std::unordered_map<std::string,std:::vector<int>>` wrapped in a helper class to implement the logic of the cumulative sum:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>


struct cumsummap {
    std::unordered_map<std::string,std::vector<int>> data;
    std::vector<int> history;
    void add(const std::string& key, int value) {
         auto& v = data[key];
         int sum = (v.size() == 0) ? value : v.back() + value;
         v.push_back(sum);
         history.push_back(sum);
    }
    void print() {
        for (auto& p : data) {
            std::cout << p.first << " : ";
            for (auto& cumsum : p.second) std::cout << cumsum << " ";
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
        for (auto& h : history) {
            std::cout << h << ' ';
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    cumsummap c;
    c.add("ankit",5);
    c.add("john",6);
    c.add("ankit",3);
    c.add("ankit",3);
    c.print();
}
```

Output:

```
john : 6 
ankit : 5 8 11 
5 6 8 11
```

Note: The question & answer went through a history of clarifications, hence there is a map of vectors when a map of `int`s would be sufficient to get the last line of the output.

PS: Please note that it is important to not confuse the task you want to solve and implementation details of a solution you have in mind. "So what I want store cumulative sum of corresponding strings in a single array at their respective position of occurences." thats not **exactly** what the above code does. There are also no visible hashes, no unique integers and I have no clue what you mean with "[...] I want to convert this unique int to correct string associated with it". Nevertheless I hope the above is close enough to want you actually want to do.

PPS: "is there is no way to do with simple way without using STL" I have to mention again that using the standard library **is** the "easy way". I am not trained in writing my own containers, so my careful estimate is that writing the above without using the standard library would be >300 lines of code with uncountable numbers of bugs.

Comment: I want to maintain order in which elements are  inserted.and in single using single DS. So that I can know which value coresponds to which string. In your answer you inserted Ankit first  than John and than again Ankit twice. So order is important for me.

Comment: In my question you can see last lines which tells what I expect but I also expect one more thing that is which value belongs to which string.

Comment: @AnkitMishra to preserve order use a `std::map` rather than a `std::unodered_map`, for the second comment, I still dont get it, a small modification of your example will make you have two identical ints for two different strings, why and how do you want to have unique integers?

Comment: @AnkitMishra "and in single using single DS" no clue what that means

Comment: @AnkitMishra "ankit" with value 5. next input is "John" with value 6 .... what if the next insert is "ankit" with value 1, then there will be an entry for "ankit" with the sum of 6, ie you have 6 twice

Comment: Yes twice 6 is no prob.you misunderstood me.  I just want to remember cumulative sum of each string in order they are inserted. And also for any index value in array or whatever DS you used . I should be able to figure particularly this cumulative sum belongs to which string

Comment: what is "DS" ?!? "I should be able to figure particularly this cumulative sum belongs to which string" this is possible in the code in my answer, but you cannot map the int (eg 6) to the string (eg "ankit") unambiguously

Comment: @AnkitMishra ok I read your example again, and if you want exactly that "it will store arr[0]=5 , arr[1]=6 ,arr[2]=8 , arr[3]=11." it requires only minor modifications. I'll edit the answer in a second

Comment: Yes DS means suitable data structure which you use to store this numbers. It maybe vector of string and int.   Order of cumulative sum is important. And no different string cumulative sum should overlap. And at any number we should be able to figure out at this index cumulative sum belongs to this string. I think best data structure to store this value is `vector<string,int>v`

Comment: the suiteable data structure is a map. why dont you want to belive that?!?

Comment: Yes we can use map.

Comment: So tell me how will I know value at index 2 which is 8 here belongs to which string.

Comment: You did awesome . I know how to make little change to take out my output. Thank you.

Comment: @Ankit you asked for an array that has the sums in the order of the entries being inserted. You cannot kknow what number corresponds to what string from that array alone, but that is what you asked for, well actually I still dont really know what you ask for

Comment: Yes o know . But `vector<string,int>v1;` may help?

Comment: @Ankit btw no I didnt do "awesome", what happened here is what I would call answering gone terribly wrong. Your question is still extremely unclear and I was stupid enough to feed you with code. Acutally I am considering to delete this, but I cant because it is the accepted answer.